# ListView Added Duplicate item in list when screen orientation changes

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter, android-orientation

I trying to create List View i face some problem when orientation changes.
Problem is: when i changes orientation of screen list-view add duplicate list item in list. how to restrict this data change

Code Is:

```
   public class DayPlannerActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtHeader;
    private Context mContext;
    private ListView lvDayplanner;
    private DayPlannerAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private static Vector<DayPlanner> list = new Vector<DayPlanner>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dayplanner);
        mContext = this;    
        activity = this;
        txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
        txtHeader.setText(R.string.haivlate);
        String[] Checks = {"select","Check1","Check2"};
        DayPlanner dp = new  DayPlanner("11:00 PM", Checks);
        list.add(dp);
        dp = new  DayPlanner("12:00 PM", Checks);
        list.add(dp);
        lvDayplanner = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDayplanner);
        adapter= new DayPlannerAdapter(activity,list);
        lvDayplanner.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

}
```

List Adapter :

```
   public class DayPlannerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private static Vector<DayPlanner> list;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;
    public DayPlannerAdapter ( Activity _activity,Vector<DayPlanner> _list) {
        mActivity = _activity;
        list = _list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)mActivity.getSystemService(mActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView txtScheduledTime;
        public Spinner spnrChecks;
        public Button btnGo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         View vi=convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dayplanner_listitem, null);
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtScheduledTime=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtScheduledTime);
                holder.spnrChecks = (Spinner) vi.findViewById(R.id.spnrChecks);
                holder.btnGo = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
                vi.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
              holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

            holder.txtScheduledTime.setText(list.get(position).getScheduledTime());
            ArrayAdapter<String> spnrAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActivity,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.get(position).getChecks());
            spnrAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);   
            holder.spnrChecks.setAdapter(spnrAdapter);

            holder.btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Intent i = new Intent();
                     i.setClass(mActivity,DayPlannerFormActivity.class);
                     mActivity.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Android automatically saves `View`s states when the orientation changes, you need a way to know if it's not the first call to `onCreate`. Luckily, it's easy: Override `onSaveInstanceState`, and store even 1 value to make the bundle your get in `onCreate` not-null.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outInstanceState) {
    outInstanceState.putInt("value", 1);
}
```

Then, when the activity is recreated, the parameter `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate` will *not* be null. So just do the test:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null)
```

Before you add data to your views.

Answer (score 2):

its because your list of dayplanner objects is static, so when you change the orientation of the view it recreates the activity but since in java a static object is not recreated, but saved for that type, it makes the list have two of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Way too late the party here,will still answer as it might be useful to someone else. I was also having the same issue it was resolved by `PROPERLY implementing the view holder design pattern`.

Comment: I can, but I won't as there are a ton of examples that you can find online.